# How to set Bit width/precision of the depth buffer(z buffer) in OGRE?

Tags: precision, ogre, depth-buffer

I read that the zbuffer_value can be found using

```
z_buffer_value = (1<<N) * ( a + b / z )
```

Where:

```
N = number of bits of Z precision
a = zFar / ( zFar - zNear )
b = zFar * zNear / ( zNear - zFar )
z = distance from the eye to the object
```

I am using OGRE 1.82. How do I set/know the number "N" ? I checked the OGRE::depthbuffer class but found no hint for the number N.
I am using Nvidia GTX TitanX

Answer (score 0):

Cross-post: [Same question ogre3d.org/forums](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=89958)

---

You can get the bit depth of the depth buffer via this method:

```
uint16 DepthBuffer::getBitDepth() const
```

[API link](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.8/group___render_system.html#ga728fb1f26362f18ea1ba9ff5fc263b05)